# Applying FactoryGirl trait to Mongoid embedded objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, factory-bot

I am building a Rails 3.2.11 application with Mongoid.  I test with Cucumber and create test objects with FactoryGirl.  I have embedded objects. I want to be able to use FactoryGirl traits with both my parent and embedded objects to make lots of permutations and keep things DRY.

**The problem:** I can't seem to get traits to apply to the embedded objects.

**model.rb** (actually, separate model files)

```
class User    
   include Mongoid::Document

   #Fields and stuff
   embeds_one :car
end

class Car    
   include Mongoid::Document

   #Fields and stuff
   embedded_in :user 
end
```

**spec/factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do

    status 'active'     # shared attribute  

    trait :bob do
     name 'Bob'
     email 'bob@bob.com'
    end

    trait :carol do
     name 'Carol'
     email 'carol@carol.com'
    end

    car  { [FactoryGirl.build(:car)] }

  end

  factory :car do

    number_of_tires 4   # shared attribute

    trait :red_ford do
     make 'Ford'
     color 'Red'
    end

    trait :blue_chevy do
     make 'Chevy'
     color 'Blue'
    end

  end
end
```

**features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb** (not working right)

```
Given /^There is a user Bob with a Blue Chevy$/ do
  FactoryGirl.create(:user, :bob, :car => [:car => :blue_chevy])
end
```

I can factory create the user object just fine if I leave off the embedded object trait.  Any way to get the embedded object to be built with the desired trait applied? Thanks!

**The fix**

Joshua Clayton at Thoughtbot http://joshuaclayton.me says:

> There's no shorthand syntax for applying traits to associations;
>   basically, you'd have to do something like this:

```
cars = [FactoryGirl.build(:car, :blue_chevy)]
FactoryGirl.create(:user, :bob, cars: cars)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is a 1 to 1 relationship, you do not need the array when building the car object in spec/factories.rb

`car  { FactoryGirl.build(:car) }`

This applies in the cucumber step as well. Also, as I understand, traits are used as attributes, so your step code should look like

`FactoryGirl.create(:user, :bob, :car, :blue_chevy)`